# vector size does not change after delete c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector class `vector<VectorClass*> myVector;` After `myVector.push_back(*data);` was called for 10 times, I tried to delete the vector class. Initial size shows 10.

After deleting, the cout the size and it still shows 10. Am I not deleting it right?

```
cout << myVector.size(); // myVector.size() = 10

if(myVector.size() > 0){
  for (vector<VectorClass*>::iterator it = myVector.begin() ; it != myVector.end(); ++it){
     *it = 0;
     delete[] *it;
   }
}

cout << myVector.size(); // myVector.size() = 10
```

Comment: Do you actually need to destroy the objects inside the vector? Or is that your attempt to destroy the vector itself, and the elements weren't dynamically allocated to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the content of elements of a vector will not reduce the size of vector, but you are not even deleting your content correctly, Because you assign `null` to each pointer and then use `delete[]`, So nothing will happen.

remove `*it = 0;` before deleting (put it after delete maybe, not important), then delete each element content and your loop finished use `myVector.clear()` to clear your vector and set size to zero.

Comment: Not sure why downvote, Is this a wrong approach? can someone please clarify?

Comment: I think what you said is correct. Don't know why the down vote.

Comment: Nothing is deleted in OP code. `*it = 0; delete[] *it;` is `delete[] nullptr`.

Comment: @S.M. Uh I didn't see that! Thanks for pointing out, So is this invalidate this answer since OP asked about `vector` size? If yes tell me to delete my answer.

Comment: In general your answer is ok, I did not downvote it. I wanted to notice you about incorrect OP approach to deleting vector elements, so you may update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting`*)` to delete each element in the vector, but not removing the pointers from the vector.  You should empty the vector after this operation, unless the vector is about to go out of scope.  Your code can be simplified a bit, too.  Replace this:

```
if(myVector.size() > 0){
  for (vector<VectorClass*>::iterator it = myVector.begin() ; it != myVector.end(); ++it){
     *it = 0;
     delete[] *it;
   }
}
```

with this:

```
for (auto a : myVector)
{
    delete[] a;
}
myVector.clear();
```

Also note that you should only use `delete[]` if you allocated each element with `new[]`.  If you allocated with `new`, you should use `delete`.

And, if you allocated with `new`, you should consider declaring the vector as `vector<VectorClass> myVector;`  That would get rid of the need to manually `delete` each element.

`*)` I say that you are **attempting** to delete each element because you assign a null pointer to each element prior to using `delete[]` on it.  That renders the `delete[]` pointless.

Comment: Nothing is deleted in OP code. `*it = 0; delete[] *it;` is `delete[] nullptr`.

Comment: @S.M. Good catch.  Surely, that must be a bug ?  I'll address it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to remove **all** elements of the vector? Then the proposed solution with `clear` will be ok.

If you want only to delete some elements you need to use `std::vector::erase`. See also